# Creating a delimited list with indirectly joined groups

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a comma-separated string of related rows, where the rows can be linked by one of two columns, but not each row does not need to have a direct join to each other row in the group. For example, say the table script is:

```
select 'A' col1, null col2, 2000 year from dual
union all select 'B' col1, 'A' col2, 2000 year from dual
union all select 'C' col1, 'B' col2, 2000 year from dual
union all select 'D' col1, null col2, 2000 year from dual
union all select 'D' col1, null col2, 2001 year from dual
union all select 'C' col1, 'E' col2, 2000 year from dual
union all select 'C' col1, null col2, 2000 year from dual
union all select 'A' col1, 'B' col2, 2002 year from dual
```

So the table looks like this:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | year |
+------+------+------+
| A    |      | 2000 |
| B    | A    | 2000 |
| C    | B    | 2000 |
| D    |      | 2000 |
| D    |      | 2001 |
| C    | E    | 2000 |
| C    |      | 2000 |
| A    | B    | 2002 |
+------+------+------+
```

The delimited list is based on each combination of linked col1 or col2, as well as the year. Nulls and duplicates are excluded, and the values in the list are sorted by name. So the new column would like the list column below for each row:

```
+------+------+------+---------+
| col1 | col2 | year |  list   |
+------+------+------+---------+
| A    |      | 2000 | A,B,C,E |
| B    | A    | 2000 | A,B,C,E |
| C    | B    | 2000 | A,B,C,E |
| D    |      | 2000 | D       |
| D    |      | 2001 | D       |
| C    | E    | 2000 | A,B,C,E |
| C    |      | 2000 | A,B,C,E |
| A    | B    | 2002 | A,B     |
+------+------+------+---------+
```

I was thinking of using listagg for this, but it didn't seem possible since not each row in the group can be joined directly to some of the other rows in the group.

Edit: The purpose of this is to create a unique identifier that can be used to order the table by year, keeping the groups together.

So for instance, we could have this example table:

```
  +-----+------+------+
  |col1 | col2 | year |
  +-----+------+------+
 1| F   |      | 2000 |
 2| G   |      | 2000 |
 3| H   | I    | 2000 |
 4| L   | N    | 2000 |
 5| F   | R    | 2000 |
 6| Z   | R    | 2000 |
 7| G   | Z    | 2000 |
 8| X   | T    | 2000 |
 9| R   |      | 2000 |
10| T   | Y    | 2000 |
  +-----+------+------+
```

So in this example table, rows 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, and 9 would be part of the same group, followed by row 3, row 4, and then by another group made up of rows 8 and 10.

That table sorted with groups moved together would look like this:

```
  +-----+------+------+
  |col1 | col2 | year |
  +-----+------+------+
 1| F   |      | 2000 |
 5| F   | R    | 2000 |
 2| G   |      | 2000 |
 7| G   | Z    | 2000 |
 9| R   |      | 2000 |
 6| Z   | R    | 2000 |
 3| H   | I    | 2000 |
 4| L   | N    | 2000 |
10| T   | Y    | 2000 |
 8| X   | T    | 2000 |
  +-----+------+------+
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the logic of the example. Can you trace through why the first list is "A, B, C, E" (and doesn't include D)?

Comment: Don't store comma separated values in a column in the database unless you are not interested in using individual values.

Comment: For future reference, please explain the business rules you want to implement, instead of leaving it to us to reverse-engineer them from the input and output. The more information you provide the more likely you are to get a helpful and timely response.

Comment: @EdmCoff The way the linking works is that either col1 or col2 is the same as col1 or col2 on another row for that year. So the row with the A links to B:A on the shared A value. Then B:A links to C:B on the shared B value. C:B links to C:E on the shared C value. C:E links to C on the shared C value. None of these values link to the D row.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather procedural approach but it produces the required output.

The first subquery gives the set of linked COL1, COL2 values; your question doesn't defined *"linked"* but you appear to mean, for a given year the values of COL2 and any instance of COL1 which has COL2 populated. The second subquery produces the obverse set of unlinked COL1 values. The third subquery generates the concatenated lists from the output of the first two subqueries.

```
with cte as 
  ( select year, col1 from t23 where col2 is not null
    union 
    select year, col2 as col1 from t23 where col2 is not null
    )
    , cte2 as 
    ( select year, col1 from t23 
       where (year, col1) not in (select year, col1 from cte) 
       )
    , cte3 as (
       select year, col1
              , listagg (cte.col1, ', ') within group (order by cte.col1) 
                                                  over (partition by year) as list
       from cte 
        union 
       select year, col1
              , listagg (cte2.col1, ', ') within group (order by cte2.col1) 
                                                 over ( partition by year) as list
       from cte2 
   )
select t23.*
       , cte3.list
from t23
     join cte3 on cte3.year = t23.year 
     and cte3.col1 = t23.col1
;
```

Here is [a LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/g152z1e7f6sxlbs9k0e9aewqc). (Alas, free Oracle login is required; I would have used SQLFiddle but that site is currently down for Oracle).